# Why does rownames(installed.packages()) have a names attribute?

Tags: r

I have the following function for personal use.  It takes in an author's name to see if I have any of their packages on my machine.

```
authoredPackages <- function (author) 
{
    s <- sapply(rownames(installed.packages()), 
        packageDescription, fields = "Author")
    names(grep(author, s, value = TRUE))
}
```

Here's the problem.  Upon opening a new R session and assigning the function, the first call to the function **always** returns a character vector of empty strings the correct length of the vector it's supposed to return.  To show this, open a new R session, assign the function, and run it with your favorite package author's surname.  It should first return an empty character vector ...

```
authoredPackages("Temple Lang")
# [1] "" "" "" ""
```

... and then do it again and it returns the correct result ...

```
authoredPackages("Temple Lang")
# [1] "jsonlite" "RCurl"    "RJSONIO"  "XML"
```

It always only happens on the first call in a new R session.   Why does this happen, and how can I fix it so the function always works on the first try?

My `R --vanilla` session info:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

**Update:** Upon opening R, is seems `rownames(installed.packages())` has a `names` attribute because of the `lme4` package.  Not sure why, and it's the only name. It's also very strange how it disappears on the second call.

```
rownames(installed.packages())[228]
#   ret0 
# "lme4"
```

Comment: Starting with R --vanilla? `sessionInfo()`? for me `authoredPackages()` works as expected for R version 3.1.2 Patched (2014-10-31 r66919) / Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit) and R Under development (unstable) (2014-11-23 r67046) / Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: seems like `ret0` is mentioned in the `installed.packages` source, when noCache=FALSE toward the end of the function; maybe adding `noCache=TRUE` as an argument is a work-around?

Comment: @MartinMorgan: Nice guess, but adding `noCache=TRUE` still yields the same odd results for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Odd, but seems like `rownames(installed.packages())` has a `names` attribute the first time you call it.

```
> str(rownames(installed.packages()))
 Named chr [1:125] "bdsmatrix" "bitops" "blotter" "brew" "car" "changepoint" "chron" "colorout" ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:125] "" "" "" "" ...
> str(rownames(installed.packages()))
 chr [1:125] "bdsmatrix" "bitops" "blotter" "brew" "car" "changepoint" "chron" "colorout" "colorspace" ...
```

---

Sorry, that left it to you to answer the question.  Just make sure there are no names.  This is a problem for you because you're relying on `sapply`'s default of `USE.NAMES=TRUE`, but that only adds names if they're not already present. And they're present for some really weird reason.

```
authoredPackages <- function (author) 
{
    r <- setNames(rownames(installed.packages()), NULL)
    s <- sapply(r, function(x) packageDescription(x)$Author)
    names(grep(author, s, value = TRUE))
}
```

Here's my `sessionInfo` (from starting with `R --vanilla`):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

---

I just upgraded to R-3.1.2 and tried again.  I still get the same odd results, and I get them consistently if I use [@MartinMorgan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116593/why-does-rownamesinstalled-packages-have-a-names-attribute/27116647#comment42737154_27116593)'s suggestion to use `noCache=TRUE`.

```
> str(rownames(installed.packages(noCache=TRUE)))
 Named chr [1:125] "bdsmatrix" "bitops" "blotter" "brew" "car" "changepoint" "chron" "colorout" ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:125] "" "" "" "" ...
> str(rownames(installed.packages(noCache=TRUE)))
 Named chr [1:125] "bdsmatrix" "bitops" "blotter" "brew" "car" "changepoint" "chron" "colorout" ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:125] "" "" "" "" ...
> str(rownames(installed.packages(noCache=TRUE)))
 Named chr [1:125] "bdsmatrix" "bitops" "blotter" "brew" "car" "changepoint" "chron" "colorout" ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:125] "" "" "" "" ...
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] setwidth_1.0-3 colorout_1.0-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```